# Windows / Web Form to other classes, forms, and etc

Tags: c#, forms, class, containers

So this particular topic has been beaten to death; but apparently my iteration is either not the method of choice or isn't practical for implementation.

The goal is to create a Windows Form and a Web Form.  Those two forms; set a property in a separate class.  Then other classes reference the container; that way as the interface is changed the functionality will change without a lot of recoding.

Windows Form ---> Container <--- Web Form
                  Container --> Referenced by these: Class 1, Class 2, Class 3

I approached it like this:
Form:

```
private Some.Reference.ToClass.Container _container;
public void Method(Some.Reference.ToClass.Container Container)
{
          _container = Container;
}

private void button_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
          _container.Name = textbox.Text (or some other component)
}
```

Class: "Container"

```
public Name { get; set; }
```

Class or Form to Reference:

```
Class WhateverName
{
       private string REFERENCE;

       private Some.Reference.ToClass.Container _container;
       public void Method(Some.Reference.ToClass.Container Container)
       {
                _container = Container;
       }

       public void NewMethod()
       {
              REFERENCE = _container.Name;
       }
}
```

It continually doesn't set; it states it's a null object.  What am I missing?  Any help would be appreciated. Or even a nice tutorial for me to compare to learn; or find why it doesn't work would be fine as well.

Comment: When you say "it continually doesn't set".. what doesn't set specifically? This is classic MVP style stuff..

Comment: It says "System.NullReferenceException {"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."} 

Which is weird; cause I'm referencing it.  At least I think I am based on that code above.

Comment: I don't see any constructor calls. does your calling code ensure that container is set via 'method' before button_Click() and NewMethod() are run?

Comment: On both buttons; the form and one of the classes.

Comment: Show us how you're instantiating both the `WhateverName` class and the `Container` in the Form.

Comment: Let me rephrase. How does this: `public void Method(Some.Reference.ToClass.Container Container)` get called?

Comment: On the button click; it just says "Method()" to instantiate since it's within the same form.

Comment: Would a simple little sample that works; be viable?  I'm not fully understanding.  I do apologize; I wish I wasn't so useless at the moment.

Comment: @greg: Note that _container is null unless Method() is called, passing in an instance of container. if button_Click() is called while _container is still null, you will get the exception you described. at least wrap the call in 'if(_container != null)'

Comment: @FrankThomas Thank you very much; so for some reason it won't let me physically call the method; it gives me: "No overload method." So on the button; if I call the method. Shouldn't _container.FirstName = Component.Text; be a valid pass so the method correctly passes? Or am I missing something.  I do appreciate yours and Simons Assistance.

Comment: Do you know of a clean way to accomplish what I'm trying to do?  As clearly my syntax is riddled with architectural faults and difficulties apparently.

Comment: @FrankThomas Is this approach bad; the goal is to have the Form physically set the property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the details provided; including the issue with the null value.  I set a Constructor to automatically initialize based upon the change.  Then just added some null reference check.

An example of this resolution:

```
public class One
{

    // declared:
    private.some.Reference.ToSomeClass _container;

    One(ToSomeClass container)
    {
          _container = container;
    }

    private void button_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
          if(_container != null)
          {
               _container.Name = textbox.Text (or some other component)
          }
    }
}
```

Then in the other class; it references the Property; for it to be set.  So to avoid it failing cause a value hasn't been assigned yet or an instance hasn't been created just added a null reference verification.